# Zeroes of the Euler class

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

Consider the Euler class of a manifold $e(\mathcal{M})$ in 4D given by

$$e(\mathcal{M}) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\epsilon_{abcd}~\Omega^{ab}\wedge\Omega^{cd}$$ where $\Omega$ is the curvature two-form. I want to find the space of all connection such that $e(\mathcal{M}) = 0$. Has this been done before and if so how? And do these connections have any special names?

Comment: Isn't the Euler characteristic not dependent on the connection because it's a topological invariant?

Comment: @memerson The integral of it is not dependent on the connection. But the Euler characteristic is dependent on the connection. In fact, it changes by an exact form if you transform the connection infinitesimally. This is the Chern-Weil theorem i am talking about.

Comment: Euler characteristic is a number, not a form.

Comment: I think you might be talking about the Euler class, not the Euler characteristic

Comment: @memerson oops!

Comment: It's still wrong: A characteristic class is an element of the cohomology ring. You can your object the "Euler form".

Comment: Yes, you're talking about differential forms representing cohomology classes. The form representing the Euler class is called the Pfaffian of $\Omega$, for example. You're asking when a zero cohomology class is represented by the zero form in some connection.

Comment: Connections having curvature 2 form $\Omega = 0$ are called flat, this is a subspace of the space you are looking for. You could try to vary a flat connection by a one form and see what conditions this one form needs to fullfill such that the euler form stays zero.